# AWS Amplify Authenticator and React Native Navigation Container how to switch between the two

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

Im building an app using React Native and am using the AWS authenticator for the sign in process.

Originally all of the components including the  component were inside the  and I was using a command of "props.onStateChage('destination')" to navigate through the different components. Everything was working great. But I thought it wouldn't be a good idea in the long run to have ALL components inside of the "Authenticator" so I switched to the section below.

After signing in, using the  component in the  I'm trying to switch the state to the  component found in the <Stack.Navigator>. However the <Stack.Navigator> throws an error because the  isn't a <Stack.Screen>.

Original:

```
const App = () => {

  return (
      <Authenticator 
          usernameAttributes="email"
          hideDefault={true}
          authState="signIn"
          > 
          <SignUp/>
          <SignIn/>
          <Home/>
          <ConfirmSignUp/>
          <ConfirmSignIn/>
          <ForgotPasswordSend/> 
        </Authenticator>
  )
}
```

After Switch:

```
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

console.disableYellowBox = true;

const Stack = createStackNavigator();



const App = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      

      <Stack.Navigator>
      <Authenticator 
          usernameAttributes="email"
          hideDefault={true}
          authState="signIn"
          > 
          <SignUp/>
          <SignIn/>
          <ConfirmSignUp/>
          <ConfirmSignIn/>
          <ForgotPasswordSend/> 
        </Authenticator>
    
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component = {Home}
        />
        
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>

  )
}
```

QUESTION SUMMARY: How do I communicate between the two?

Personal Attempt:
I tried moving the  into its own component called  which had the original code in it and then made  into a <Stack.Screen> but now I'm getting an error that 'props.onStateChange' is not a function. It was working earlier.

Heres a link to the tutorial I've been following for more insight, There are multiple videos in the series but this is one of them to point in the right direction:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoghLcZjVCE

Comment: There is a problem with your question - there is no question.

Comment: @JohnH Everything inside the <Authenticator> was working when the Home component was also inside. To change states I was using a command of props.onStateChange('Pagename',{}); with the destination page name in place of Pagename. The <Stack.Navigator> would throw an error because of the <Authenticator> though so Im trying to figure out how to go from a button press in the SignIn component in the <Authenticator> to change the state to the Home screen in the <StackNavigator>.

Comment: @JohnH Im not sure what happened but for some reason now its telling me that props.onStateChange isnt a command when it was working in the past. Heres a link to the tutorial I followed, if it provides some clarity. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZen4RTUnqY

Comment: Asking a specific question about your problem can help others provide answers to help you. If you have already resolved some or all of your problem, consider an edit of your question with that information.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I've switched from the < Authenticator > to a second <Stack.Navigator> which I named <AuthenticatorStack.Navigator> and can now transfer between the two.

The authenticator still uses the 'Auth' calls for signing in, but encapsulating the authenticator in a 'Navigator' tag made it easier. For more info look up: Nesting Navigators, or follow this link. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/